# Set Row height in Excel through OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I have the code for generating an Excel sheet and I want to set the Row height there.

The code is as follows:

```
Columns lstColumns = sheet1.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<Columns>();

bool needToInsertColumns = false;
if (lstColumns == null)
{
    lstColumns = new Columns();
    needToInsertColumns = true;
}

lstColumns.Append(
     new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 1, Width = 120, CustomWidth = true }
);

if (needToInsertColumns)
{
    sheet1.Worksheet.InsertAt(lstColumns, 0);
}

// For rows.
Row row;
row = new Row() { RowIndex = 1 };
row.Height = 100;

sheetData.Append(row);
```

Through the following code I am able to set the width but not the height.

Comment: You are inserting *columns*, and it doesn't make much sense to set the height of a column, does it? You have to get the *rows* you want, then set their height. As far as I remember, you can also set default cell height/width for the entire sheet, if that matches your needs

Comment: I have updated the question Rafalon. I have set the height there but I could not get the required height.

Comment: Can't you just use `sheetData.SetRowHeight(1, 100);` instead of *appending* a new `Row`? Or this one: `sheetData.Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 100;`?

Comment: It is popping an error stating sheetData doesnt have a definition for Rows and no accessible extension method 'Rows' accepting first Argument of type 'SheetData'

Comment: My bad, try with `sheet1.Worksheet` instead of `sheetData`

Comment: Same Error even after replacing it with sheet1.worksheet and in the official documentation, there is no method called SetRowHeight or Rows.

Comment: What type exactly is your `sheet1` (including namespace)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197880/discussion-between-roopteja-and-rafalon).

Comment: DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.Worksheetpart is the type of sheet1

Comment: you forgot to set CustomHeight = true

Answer (score 4):

Do the following:

```
 Row row;
 row = new Row() { RowIndex = 1 };
 row.Height = 10.0;
 row.CustomHeight = true;
```

or,  better:

```
 var row = new Row { Height = 10.0, CustomHeight = true, RowIndex = 1 };
```

The CustomHeight property is important here.